# How to create a dynamic excel link in VB.NET? (not .dll)

Tags: vb.net, excel, user-interface

VB.NET level: Beginner

I made a .exe using VB.NET. In this program there are many links to excel files (There are specific folders for excel files).

My problem:

Consider an excel file named as abc.xlsx, which is on my home pc. Link to this file is as follows,
D:\work\data\abc.xlsx

now for obvious reasons, this link will not be valid when I run the .exe on my work pc.
(Later I want to run this .exe on multiple pc's)

How to solve this issue?

My thinking is to create a dynamic link which will update itself based on pc in use or to create a constant link which is independent of pc in use.

Help will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking how to substitute a different directory for "D:\work\data" ?

Comment: @hometoast: To some extent yes. All I want to make sure is my excel files can be opened from .exe on any pc. (I will create a folder file containing all the excel files and ship this folder with my .exe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so make the path relative to the .exe

C:\myapp\myapp.exe
c:\myapp\data\abc.xslx
...

So no matter where you app is, you can get to your data like this

```
Dim dataFolder As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(‌​).Location)
dataFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(dataFolder,"data")
Dim theFileIwant as String = System.IO.Path.Combine(datafolder,"abc.xslx")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
   Public Function GetDynamicFilename(p_filename As String) As String

      Dim tempPath As String

      Select Case My.Computer.Name.ToUpper
         Case "COMPUTER1"
            tempPath = "c:\work\data"
         Case "COMPUTER2"
            tempPath = "d:\work\files"
      End Select

      Return String.Format("{0}\{1}", tempPath, p_filename)

   End Function
```

Comment: I am sorry if this sounds stupid, but do i need to identify all such cases?

Comment: If you can't standardize the file location, then yes.  You could do a search for the file, but that may take time.  You could also collect an entered file location once and store it in a config file to reload everytime and use that as well.  Lots of options, just don't know what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: Another thought, if the file is relative to the program executable location, you could set it that way.  Something along the lines of this:        Return String.Format("{0}\data\{1}", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, p_filename) 'given the file is always in a subdirectory of the application.

Comment: Almost -1 for using `String.Format` instead of `Path.Combime`!

Comment: Wow, never heard of that method.  Not sure I would like to use that because of some of the rules it uses ("c:\temp" & "temp.txt" results "c:\temp.txt" instead of "c:\temp\temp.txt" like I would expect).